# Server.MapPath not returning expected path

Tags: asp-classic

I've been handed alegacy (Classic ASP), red headed step child who has been beaten, shot and otherwise maimed by a number of people before my time, application and for the life of me I can't figure out how it's actually working on production (I even got a copy from production just in case the files weren't up to date in source control).

I have code that does the following

```
tmpDefaultXSLFile="xsl/SomeValue"
...
objXsl.load(Server.MapPath(tmpDefaultXSLFile & ".xsl"))
```

However, Server.MapPath seems not to map the file to the expected location (i.e."\asp_file_directory\xsl\SomeValue.xsl" and the modification required is to the xsl file.

Is there ANY way that the system could be fooled into have Server.MapPath map somewhere else?

Comment: What happens when you write the value of the `Server.MapPath(tmpDefaultXSLFile & ".xsl")` to the web page ? What value does it give ? Is the xls folder really a sub folder of the plade where the asp files are stored ? And do you have write access in this file ( assuming you want to update the xsl file ?

Comment: Looks like I stumbled upon code that isn't ever called.  Chalk this one up to vestigle software organs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like virtual directory on IIS is causing this. Check the URL and compare it to the directory structure within IIS including the virtual.

Comment: Yep, for example if `/xsl` is mapped (as virtual directory) to different physical directory, that different directory will be used as the root..

Answer (score 0):

server.mappath(Path) specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (\), the MapPath method returns a path as if Path is a full virtual path.

If Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

Comment: He didn't ask what `MapPath` is doing, he asked for ideas why it might give wrong result.

Comment: the problem is he did not app;y the slash mark correctly for his desired result. my post was to inform how to correctly use the slash mark to achieve the desired path information. don't mark down because you assume only you are right.  my post is the best answer for this question because it is a complete solution.